# React functions accessing state or props: Better inside component/hook within useCallback or outside with state/props as input?

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization

Example 1:

```
const Counter = (props: {color: string}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(100)
  
  const needMore = useCallback(() => {
    if(count === 0) {
      console.log('need more')
    }
  }, [count])

  const allowNegative = useCallback(() => {
    if(props.color === 'red' && count < 0) {
      console.log('allowed')
    }
  }, [count, props.color])


  return (
   <>
     <h1>{count}</h1>
     <button onClick={needMore}>A</button>
     <button onClick={allowNegative}>B</button>
   </>
}
```

Example 2:

```
const needMore = (count: number) => {
  if (count === 0) {
    console.log('need more');
  }
};

const allowNegative = (color: string, count: number) => {
  if (color === 'red' && count < 0) {
    console.log('allowed');
  }
};

const Counter = (props: { color: string }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(100);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=> needMore(count)}>A</button>
      <button onClick={()=>allowNegative(props.color, count)}>B</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

From my understanding it's generally a good idea to extract functions from components as much as possible to prevent unnecessary recreactions on every render. useCallback can help with that but the function would still get recreated if the dependencies change. To prevent that we could just move the function outside and pass the state as input but in this case the amount of input parameters increases.

Which one of the two is considered to be better, and how can I decide which one to go for?
Is there perhaps another better option that I'm unaware of?

Comment: if its pure function then put outside,if its updating state then put inside

Comment: Would you say putting it outside is categorically better than inside even if it's just used by this one component (assuming a pure function)?

Comment: yes,it should be there